# How is this perfect passive participle being used?

Tags: syntax, grammar-identification, ovidius

From *Metamorphoses* book II:

> nec minus Heliades fletus et, inania morti
> munera, dant lacrimas, et
> caesae pectora palmis
> non auditurum miseras Phaethonta querellas 
> nocte
> dieque vocant adsternunturque sepulcro.

Loeb translates "caesae pectora palmis" as "With bruising hands beating their naked breasts...". But the thing I don't understand is that *caesus* is "having been beaten", not "having beaten". I would have expected the inflection of *caesus* to agree with *pectora*, not *Heliades* (or implicit *illae*). But *pectora* is nom./acc. **neuter** pl.

There's probably some very simple explanation here, but having mulled it over for an hour or so I just don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is sometimes known as the "accusative of body parts", where an accusative noun indicates the body part (or more generally, the part of something) where an action takes place.

They (nom) were struck (nom) by palms (abl) on their breasts (acc).